# How to read xml attribute value on apache ant?

Tags: ant

I have an xml like below.

```
  <Students college="SGS">
     <Student id="001" name="ABC"/>
     <Student id="002" name="XYZ"/>
  <Students/>
  <Students college="SPM">
    <Student id="001" name="PQR"/>
    <Student id="002" name="LMN"/>
  <Students/>
```

and I want name of the student of the SGS college whose id is 001 using apache ant.
So how can I get this without using extra jar like xmltask.jar etc

Comment: Can you post the solution you implemented ?

Comment: <xmltask source="source.xml"> 
      <copy path="/Students/Student[0][@id]/text()" property="prop1"/>  
</xmltask>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) to get this information. In Ant there is no built-in task to fetch XML data using XPath expressions. You would need to use tasks provided in external libraries:

https://code.google.com/p/ant-xpath-task/wiki/Introduction

http://ant.apache.org/external.html